Generic type-hinting for kwargs
I'm trying to wrap the signal class of blinker with one that enforces typing so that the arguments to send and connect get type-checked for each specific signal.
eg if I have a signal user_update which expects sender to be an instance of User and have exactly two kwargs: time: int, audit: str, I can sub-class Signal to enforce that like so:
class UserUpdateSignal(Signal):
  class Receiver(Protocol):
    def __call__(sender: User, /, time: int, audit: str):
      ...

  def send(sender: User, /, time: int, audit: str):
    # super call

  def connect(receiver: Receiver):
    # super call

which results in the desired behavior when type-checking:
user_update.send(user, time=34, audit="user_initiated") # OK

@user_update.connect # OK
def receiver(sender: User, /, time: int, audit: str):
    ...

user_update.send("sender") # typing error - signature mismatch

@user_update.connect # typing error - signature mismatch
def receiver(sender: str):
    ...

The issues with this approach are:

it's very verbose, for a few dozen signals I'd have hundreds of lines of code
it doesn't actually tie the type of the send signature to that of the connect signature - they can be updated independently, type-checking would pass, but the code would crash when run

The ideal approach would apply a signature defined once to both send and connect - probably through generics. I've tried a few approaches so far:
Positional Args Only with ParamSpec
I can achieve the desired behavior using only
class TypedSignal(Generic[P], Signal):
    def send(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs):
        super().send(*args, **kwargs)

    def connect(self, receiver: Callable[P, None]):
        return super().connect(receiver=receiver)


user_update = TypedSignal[[User, str]]()

This type-checks positional args correctly but has no support for kwargs due to the limitations of Callable. I need kwargs support since blinker uses kwargs for every arg past sender.
Other Attempts
Using TypeVar and TypeVarTuple
I can achieve type-hinting for the sender arg pretty simply using generics:
T = TypeVar("T")

class TypedSignal(Generic[T], Signal):
    def send(self, sender: Type[T], **kwargs):
        super(TypedSignal, self).send(sender)

    def connect(self, receiver: Callable[[Type[T], ...], None]) -> Callable:
        return super(TypedSignal, self).connect(receiver)

# used as
my_signal = TypedSignal[MyClass]()

what gets tricky is when I want to add type-checking for the kwargs. The approach I've been attempting to get working is using a variadic generic and Unpack like so:
T = TypeVar("T")
KW = TypeVarTuple("KW")

class TypedSignal(Generic[T, Unpack[KW]], Signal):
    def send(self, sender: Type[T], **kwargs: Unpack[Type[KW]]):
        super(TypedSignal, self).send(sender)

    def connect(self, receiver: Callable[[Type[T], Unpack[Type[KW]]], None]) -> Callable:
        return super(TypedSignal, self).connect(receiver)

but mypy complains: error: Unpack item in ** argument must be a TypedDict which seems odd because this error gets thrown even with no usage of the generic, let alone when a TypedDict is passed.
Using ParamSpec and Protocol
P = ParamSpec("P")

class TypedSignal(Generic[P], Signal):
    def send(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> None:
        super().send(*args, **kwargs)

    def connect(self, receiver: Callable[P, None]):
        return super().connect(receiver=receiver)


class Receiver(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, sender: MyClass) -> None:
        pass

update = TypedSignal[Receiver]()


@update.connect
def my_func(sender: MyClass) -> None:
    pass

update.send(MyClass())

but mypy seems to wrap the protocol, so it expects a function that takes the protocol, giving the following errors:
 error: Argument 1 to "connect" of "TypedSignal" has incompatible type "Callable[[MyClass], None]"; expected "Callable[[Receiver], None]"  [arg-type]
 error: Argument 1 to "send" of "TypedSignal" has incompatible type "MyClass"; expected "Receiver"  [arg-type]

Summary
Is there a simpler way to do this? Is this possible with current python typing?
mypy version is 1.9.0 - tried with earlier versions and it crashed completely.

It's not clear what you're trying to statically type. I'd encourage you to re-write the question in terms of expected errors that mypy should emit if you pass the wrong **kwargs. Based on blinker's source, I see two possible things that you might want to type check when you pass **kwargs: (1) conformance to the signature blinker.base.Signal.send and .connect, or (2) conformance to the callables in .receivers: dict[IdentityType, t.Callable | annotatable_weakref], which will receive **kwargs passed to send.

Your examples seem to hint that you want (1), but your TypedSignal.send doesn't seem to pass **kwargs to super(), so - as of your current implementation - there isn't a point in type-checking the **kwargs at all - you might as well use typing.Any or _typeshed.Unused as the annotation.

I want to create signatures for each signal that is typed. eg I'd have a user_update signal where the sender should always be a User instance and it should have a specific set of kwargs which are type-checked - I'll add details to the question

In your updated example, you allow time=34, audit="user_initiated" as keyword arguments to send. How did you choose these two keyword arguments to be conformant to send? As in - where is the original signature defined, such that send is compatible with this original signature? Or, are you looking for an API (something along the lines of TypedSignal[Receiver, <KWArgs>]) that allows you to generate a subtype of Signal that automatically checks that send conforms to <KWArgs>?

Yes, just like the second one! I'll update the question with a more descriptive answer

After a lot of trial an error, I've found a relatively simple solution, although it depends on mypy_extensions which is deprecated so this may not be entirely future-proof, although it still works on the latest mypy version.
Essentially, using mypy's NamedArg allows defining kwargs in a Callable, enabling us to simply use ParamSpec to solve this:
class TypedSignal(Generic[P], Signal):
    def send(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs):
        super().send(*args, **kwargs)

    def connect(self, receiver: Callable[P, None]):
        return super().connect(receiver=receiver)


user_update = TypedSignal[[User, NamedArg(str, "metadata")]]()

This correctly type-checks calls so that anything aside from the below:
@user_update.connect
def my_func(sender: User, metadata: str) -> None:
    pass

user_update.send(User(), metadata="metadata")

will throw an error.

I don't think this is possible.
You can annotate **kwargs in 3 ways:

**kwargs: Foo -> kwargs has type dict[str, Foo]
**kwargs: Unpack[TD] where TD is a TypedDict -> kwargs has type TD
*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs where P is a ParamSpec -> kwargs is generic over P

So the only way to have generic kwargs is to use 1. with a regular TypeVar, which means all keyword arguments need to have compatible types, or to use 3. but currently that requires you to also have *args, which you don't have.

Thanks! I tried with ParamSpec as well by converting the first arg to *args but it doesn't work because I can't find a way to define kwargs with it (similar to this issue: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/1405)

Added another approach using ParamSpec and Protocol - curious if there's anything worth trying along that line. Is there a simpler way I could use ParamSpec here?

I'm not sure. Part of the difficulty is that mypy tends to lag behind with newer typing features which sometimes means it's hard to distinguish between "using typing wrong", "this is untypable in this version of Python" and "this is untypable in this version of mypy".
